# libtorrent error on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, libtorrent

I'm trying to run a program on Windows XP using libtorrent 1.1.5 (compiled via boost 1.65.1) and get the error "The entry point to the CreateSemaphoreExW procedure was not found in the KERNEL32.dll DLL.". On Windows 7+ this works fine. How can I fix this error?

UPDATE:
`_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` solved the problem

Comment: Don't run on the XP machine? - XP is now out of support and likely will not get an update that it appears is needed.  It appears you are below the minimum system requirements needed.

Comment: You COULD try to copy the dll from Vista but I doubt it would work and might crash stuff required to run the OS.

Comment: Deluge BitTorrent Client works on the libtorrent and runs on Windows XP

Comment: @ kotbrain can you tell me how you defined _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501. It does not work for me (if_nameisindex function)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple- you can not fix it. Take a look at the official documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682446(v=vs.85).aspx

Minimum supported client: Windows Vista. You can try to download a kernel32.dll from windows 7 and put it into the application directory, but I doubt it would work.

Comment: Deluge BitTorrent Client works on the libtorrent and runs on Windows XP.